# Using Arcmap to update a field based on data from another fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to update latitude and longitude data per individual station for a lab I'm working for.

Here's some code I have that's supposed to assign any all bay stations of a certain name the appropriate GPS coordinates.

Whenever I try to run it arcMap simply says there was an error processing the data.

[image: Field Calculator]

Comment: Right off the cuff your python structure is malformed.  Read up about [proper indentation](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

Comment: Also, include the actual error message as that will usually help determine what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long is a reserved word (a type) in python so I used in_long instead.

code block:

```
def update_nones(in_long,bay_statio):
    if bay_statio==0:
        return -84.9250031
    else:
        return in_long
```

expression:

```
update_nones(!long!,!bay_statio!)
```